# Difficult definite integral with a possibly real finite answer

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

[image: The Integral]

I'm stumped here.The interval of integration would make me think to look for symmetry, but it's clearly not even or odd. I asked wolfram alpha to get any ideas, and it gave me a complex number as the value of the integral, which makes no sense. The graph seems to enclose a finite area in the interval, making me think it has a real finite answer. How do I solve this?

Comment: Hm, wasn't this asked the other day... Let me have a search. Where did you find it?

Comment: Well this is surely a duplicate but no complete answer has been given in the other thread.